# how to find and click a button with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm pretty new to programming.So i have this code its supposed to log me in at instagram but i doesnt works.
I tried to find it by x_path and other methods but didnt get it right.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import webbrowser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
webbrowser.open('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 
"C:\chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser = webbrowser
login_elem = 
webbrowser.find_element_by_xpath('//article/div/div/p/a[text()="Anmelden"]')
login_elem.click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.c_button.s_button').click()
ese.clickButton(Anmelden)
```

Comment: You need to define a timer for waiting until the components have loaded completely.
Maybe you click() action is invoked before the button is showed/loaded.

Was the problem for me - but on java, sry.

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` mean? Post the error message, etc.

Comment: thx worked for me <3.I added sleep(5) and opened it with browser.get()